# VBA - Best Way to Distinct the values and transpose the data next to them?

Tags: vba, excel

Two columns in Excel, listing the Candidate Id and the preferred city (Just part of it):

```
  A       B
6957    Ankara
6957    Antalya
6957    İstanbul
6957    İzmir
8469    İstanbul
8470    İzmir
8470    İstanbul
8499    İstanbul
8514    İstanbul
7775    Ankara
7775    Eskişehir
7775    Kastamonu
7775    Zonguldak
7775    Karabük
8532    Ankara
8532    Antalya
8532    Bursa
8532    İzmir
```

How can I make them look like below with VBA:

```
 A         B         C          D         E          F
6957    Ankara     Antalya   İstanbul   İzmir
8469    İstanbul                
8470    İzmir      İstanbul             
8499    İstanbul        
8514    İstanbul                
7775    Ankara    Eskişehir  Kastamonu  Zonguldak   Karabük
8532    Ankara    Antalya    Bursa      İzmir
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Please edit your post and show us what have you done so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following VBA macro - it worked for me on the above data:

```
Sub makeTable()
Dim inRange As Range
Dim outRange As Range
Dim currentCell, currentCandidate
Dim optionCount As Integer

Set inRange = Range("A2:A19")
Set outRange = Range("D2")

currentCandidate = inRange.Cells(1).Value
outRange.Value = currentCandidate
optionCount = 0

For Each currentCell In inRange.Cells
  If currentCell.Value = currentCandidate Then
    optionCount = optionCount + 1
  Else
    optionCount = 1
    Set outRange = outRange.Offset(1, 0)
    currentCandidate = currentCell.Value
    outRange.Value = currentCandidate
  End If
  outRange.Offset(0, optionCount) = currentCell.Offset(0, 1)

Next currentCell

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Note - this does require you to sort the data (first by candidate, then by city) but I think you already have that done.

Comment: @Floris: like your approach, it's dense and efficient :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more suggestion. It splits the work into two steps:

1. Bring the data into a new structure.
2. Write the new structure to Excel.

Sometimes it is valuable to separate the work contexts. Unlike in Floris' snippet, the key column doesn't have to be ordered.

(Algorithm was edited 06/25/14 20:30 according to the comments.)

```
Dim rIn As Range
Dim rOut As Range

Dim row As Range
Dim key
Dim value
Dim keyString As String

Dim resultCollection As Collection
Dim resultRow As Collection
Dim rowOffset As Integer
Dim columnOffset As Integer
Dim outItem

Set rIn = Range("A1:B9")
Set rOut = Range("C1")
Set resultCollection = New Collection

' 1. Loop through all rows of the input range.
For Each row In rIn.Rows

    key = row.Cells(1, 1)
    value = row.Cells(1, 2)

    keyString = CStr(key)

    ' VBA Collections cannot check if a key exists. Error checking is the way to go.
    ' Error 457 is to bear in mind: "This key is already associated with an element of this collection."
    On Error Resume Next 

    ' Try to add a new key and its collection.
    resultCollection.Add New Collection, keyString
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        ' No error means that key has just been added. Init the entry.
        resultCollection(keyString).Add keyString
    End If
    ' Here, enhanced error handling is possible.
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Here we are sure that the result collection was prepared with the right key and a collection.
    resultCollection(keyString).Add value

Next

' 2. Write the prepared resultCollectionto the sheet.
rowOffset = 0
For Each resultRow In resultCollection
    columnOffset = 0
    For Each outItem In resultRow
        rOut.Offset(rowOffset, columnOffset).value = outItem
        columnOffset = columnOffset + 1
    Next
    rowOffset = rowOffset + 1
Next
```

Remark:

Whenever you must use VBA error handling because you can't detect the situation ahead, you have these options:

1. Branch to an error handler and set some variables which will used back in the main program flow.
2. Work with `On Error Resume Next` and `err.Number` and `err.Clear`.

Both alternatives may lead to unreadable code, it depends on the situation. Here, option 1 was shorter. Further, I prefer not to have "side effects". Variables in the main program flow wondrously set by an error handler outside the main flow remind me on side effects.

In work with arrays instead of collections, you can assign the array directly to the range and spare the inner loop in part 2.

Comment: Nice use of collections - this is certainly a more flexible approach but it is a bit more resource intensive. I wonder whether with minimal changes you could make it so you don't need the keys to be sorted: if key exists, add element; else create key and single element.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I see it. If you use sth like a dictionary, you don't need to trigger for a key change and the keys don't have to be sorted. Just fill all values to the matching key, and if there is no key yet, add it with an empty collection. Glad to see, thx :-)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant. You might consider updating your answer with that alternative - would make for quite nice code that could find future use...

Comment: Code is changed now :-)